# How to set ALB rules programmatically in .ebextensions or saved configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I want to use an AWS application load balancer(ALB) to redirect all the traffics of port 80 to port 443.

I know how to configure this with AWS console:

[image]

[image]

But how can I configure this programmatically so that I don't have to set the rules every time I create a new elastic beanstalk environment?

It looks like that this http-to-https rule can be set in `.ebextension` or saved configuration, probably using the values mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listenerrule).

But I still can't figure out the way to set the rule.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Hello Brian, how are you? Do you have any progress with this issue?

Comment: No, I don't have any progress with this issue.